# How to return current decibel level from iPhone mic

Tags: ios, swiftui, avfoundation

I am trying to return the current decibel level from the iPhone's microphone. I have pieced together this code below and cannot figure out why it won't work. My expectation is that for now it will print the current peak power continuously to the console.

So my questions/issues are:

1. Will "peakPowerForchannel" return the current level or the max for the entire audio session?
2. It appears my button never turns to the stop recording mode and just prints "recording started" every time it is pressed.
3. I can't figure out why the decibel level won't print at all.

Thanks for the help!

```
import SwiftUI
import AVFoundation
import Foundation
import Combine

class AudioRecorder: ObservableObject {
    
    let objectWillChange = PassthroughSubject<AudioRecorder, Never>()
    var audioRecorder: AVAudioRecorder!
    var decibelLevelTimer = Timer()
    
    var recording = false {
        didSet {
            objectWillChange.send(self)
        }
        
    }
    
    func startRecording() {
            let recordingSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
        do {
                    try recordingSession.setCategory(.playAndRecord, mode: .default)
                    try recordingSession.setActive(true)
                } catch {
                    print("Failed to set up recording session")
                }
        let documentPath = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0]
        let audioFilename = documentPath.appendingPathComponent("\(Date().toString(dateFormat: "dd-MM-YY_'at'_HH:mm:ss")).m4a")
        let settings = [
                    AVFormatIDKey: Int(kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC),
                    AVSampleRateKey: 12000,
                    AVNumberOfChannelsKey: 1,
                    AVEncoderAudioQualityKey: AVAudioQuality.high.rawValue
                ]
        do {
                    audioRecorder = try AVAudioRecorder(url: audioFilename, settings: settings)
                    audioRecorder.record()

                    recording = true
                    audioRecorder.isMeteringEnabled = true
            self.decibelLevelTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 0.02, repeats: true) { timer in
                self.audioRecorder.updateMeters()
                print(self.audioRecorder.peakPower(forChannel: 0))
            }
                } catch {
                    print("Could not start recording")
                }
        }
    
}


extension Date
{
    func toString( dateFormat format  : String ) -> String
    {
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = format
        return dateFormatter.string(from: self)
    }
}


struct ContentView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var audioRecorder: AudioRecorder
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            if audioRecorder.recording == false {
                Button(action: {print("Start recording")}) {
                    Image(systemName: "circle.fill")
                        .resizable()
                        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                        .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                        .clipped()
                        .foregroundColor(.red)
                        .padding(.bottom, 40)
                }
            } else {
                Button(action: {print("Stop recording)")}) {
                    Image(systemName: "stop.fill")
                        .resizable()
                        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                        .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                        .clipped()
                        .foregroundColor(.red)
                        .padding(.bottom, 40)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding peak power, here's what the docs say:

> The audio channel’s current peak power.

(basically, the current window)

You need to actually call `startRecording()` in your Button's action (right now, all you're doing is printing):

```
Button(action: {
  audioRecorder.startRecording()
}) {
```

Similarly, you need to make and call a `stopRecording` action for the other button:

```
func stopRecording() {
        audioRecorder.stop()
        recording = false
        decibelLevelTimer.invalidate()
}
//....
Button(action: {
  audioRecorder.stopRecording()
}) {
```

Also, if you still don't have input, make sure your microphone permissions are set correctly: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/cameras_and_media_capture/requesting_authorization_for_media_capture_on_macos

With those changes, your code works for me.